# How to use pytest using pybuilder?

Tags: python, build, pytest, python-unittest, pybuilder

Following this [tutorial](https://pybuilder.io/documentation/tutorial) for the build tool for my project, except **pytest** was used instead of *mockito* as given there. The pytest is working fine individually, but when pybuider is running it throws an error. `Coverage.py warning: Module __init__ was never imported. (module-not-imported)` is part of the error. I tried the configuration given in [python_pybuilder](https://pypi.org/project/pybuilder-pytest/) documentation.

```
#   -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pybuilder.core import use_plugin, init

use_plugin("pypi:pybuilder_pytest")
use_plugin('pypi:pybuilder_pytest_coverage')
use_plugin("python.core")
use_plugin("python.unittest")
use_plugin("python.flake8")
# use_plugin("python.coverage")
use_plugin("python.distutils")


name = "Traffic"
default_task = "publish"


@init
def init(project):
    project.get_property("pytest_extra_args").append("-x")
```

This is my build.py